# fetch value from a given array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array stored in $result like this

```
$result=$array
```

by using echo $result i get the following array

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [product] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [seo_h1] => 
            [name] => Beer Week
            [manufacturer] => The Boxer Store
            [model] => WPEB/0413/74/BW
            [sku] => WPEB/0413/74/BW
            [reward] => 0
            [points] => 0
            [image] => asd
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => asd
                )

            [quantity] => 4
            [price] => Rs.599
            [special] => 
            [discounts] => Array
                (
                )

            [options] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_id] => 42
                            [option_id] => 25
                            [name] => Size Option
                            [type] => select
                            [option_value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product_option_value_id] => 165
                                            [option_value_id] => 72
                                            [name] => Large
                                            [option_sku] => 
                                            [image] => asd
                                            [price] => 
                                            [price_prefix] => +
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product_option_value_id] => 166
                                            [option_value_id] => 73
                                            [name] => XL
                                            [option_sku] => 
                                            [image] => asd
                                            [price] => 
                                            [price_prefix] => +
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product_option_value_id] => 163
                                            [option_value_id] => 70
                                            [name] => Small
                                            [option_sku] => 
                                            [image] => asd
                                            [price] => 
                                            [price_prefix] => +
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product_option_value_id] => 164
                                            [option_value_id] => 71
                                            [name] => Medium
                                            [option_sku] => 
                                            [image] => asd
                                            [price] => 
                                            [price_prefix] => +
                                        )

                                )

                            [required] => 1
                        )

                )

            [minimum] => 1
            [rating] => 0
            [description] => as
            [attribute_groups] => Array
                (
                )

            [date_added] => 2014-09-30 12:35:12
            [date_modified] => 2014-10-17 17:33:46
            [currency] => INR
            [status] => 1
        )

)
```

i am able to fetch the result individually like this

```
$finalid = $array['product']['id']; 
echo $finalid;
```

but wish to fetch each and every data even the inner most values using for loop. for this i tried this

```
$c=count($result);
    for ( $i=0; $i < $c; $i++)
    { 
       echo $array[$i]['id'];
       echo $array[$i]['images'][0];
       echo $array[$i]['options'][0]['product_option_id'];
       echo $array[$i]['images'][0]['option_value'][0]['product_option_value_id'];
       echo $array[$i]['images'][0]['option_value'][1]['product_option_value_id'];
    }
```

but it didn't displayed any result can anyone tell how it can be done

Comment: The array in your case is associative (in the form of key=>value). Traverse it using `foreach ($array as $i => $value) {...}`. You might have to do this recursively for the depth of nested arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    <?php

foreach($result as $res){
    echo '<pre>'; echo $res['id'];

    if(is_array($res['options']) &&  !empty($res['options'])) {
        foreach($res['options'] as $option) {
            echo '<pre>'; echo ($option['product_option_id']);


            if(is_array($option['option_value']) &&  !empty($option['option_value'])) {
                foreach($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                    echo '<pre>'; echo $option_value['product_option_value_id'];
            }


        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i got the first 3 result but for product_option_value_id, i am getting error Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: It means that your 4th array element may not have the product_option_value_id. I mean $res['images'][0]['option_value'] this may not be an array.So before each step check whether it is an array is_array($res['images'][0]['option_value'])

Comment: i have another array within option_value as shown in question, can u plz go through the array n tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: See the latest one, Edited again

Answer (score 1):

```
Use:
$products = $result['product'];
foreach ( $products as $product )
{ 
   echo $product['id'];
   echo $product['images'][0];
   echo $product['options'][0]['product_option_id'];
   echo $product['images'][0]['option_value'][0]['product_option_value_id'];
   echo $product['images'][0]['option_value'][1]['product_option_value_id'];
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error Cannot use string offset as an array

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` instead,

```
foreach ( $array['product'] as $product)
    { 
       echo $product['id'];
       echo $product['images'][0];
       echo $product['options'][0]['product_option_id'];
       echo $product['options'][0]['option_value'][0]['product_option_value_id'];
       echo $product['options'][0]['option_value'][1]['product_option_value_id'];
    }
```

Here you will be looping inside each element of `$array['product']` and for each loop `$product` will have the current element of `$array['product']`.

The mistake in your attempt was in [$i]. For each loop $i would have 0,1,2 etc and the array index would be `$array['product'][0]`,etc but there is no element of that sort. Your method works if your array is an `Indexed array`, but here it is an `Associative Array`.

Comment: i got an error  Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array for echo $product['images'][0];

Comment: Check the edited answer.
In your question, I think you had put `images` by mistake instead of `options` for the last two `echo` statements. I had just modified the main problem part.

Comment: now i am getting the value of id but still having the same error for second echo

Answer (score 1):

You may want a recursive function like this to print your multidimensional arrays:

```
function printIt($data){
    if (is_array($data)){
        foreach ($data as $index=>$slice){
            if (is_array($slice)){
                printIt($slice);
            }else{
                echo $index.": ".$slice."<br>";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo $data."<br>";
    }
}

printIt($yourArray);
```